# I am trying to create a function for the distance formula in DrRacket (Scheme) but I get an error every time I run it

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

Here is my code.

```
(define CartDist
  (lambda X1 Y1 X2 Y2
    (sqrt (+ (sqr (- X2 X1)) (sqr (- Y2 Y1))))))

(CartDist 0 0 3 4)
```

Here is the error that I receive in the interactions pane when I run it:

```
lambda: expected (lambda (variable more-variable ...) expression), but found something else
```

I have no clue as to why I get this error (I'm a student and new to scheme)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (sqr x) (* x x))

(define (cart-distance x1 x2 y1 y2)
  (sqrt (+ (sqr (- x2 x1)) (sqr (- y2 y1)))))

(define cartDistance (lambda (x1 x2 y1 y2)
                   (sqrt (+ (sqr (- x2 x1)) (sqr (- y2 y1))))))
```

This works  for me. You messed with syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate what is wrong, here is a correctly indented version:

```
(define CartDist
  (lambda X1 
    Y1 
    X2 
    Y2
    (sqrt (+ (sqr (- X2 X1)) (sqr (- Y2 Y1))))))
```

If you call it `(CartDist 0 0 3 4)` the argument binding `x1` becomes `(0 0 3 4)` since it's one symbol (a rest argument).

`y1` is the fist expression in the function to be evaluated and it will fail since it's not defined in either lexical nor global scope. Same with the other variables being evaluated before the tail expression `(sqrt ...)`. To fix that you need to put the parameters in a list so that they become boudn variables when called:

```
(define cart-dist
  (lambda (x1 y1 x2 y2)
    (sqrt (+ (sqr (- x2 x1)) 
             (sqr (- y2 y1))))))
```

I have taken the liberty to change the case and names to follow lisp style. You can also do the combination of `define` and `lambda` like this:

```
(define (cart-dist x1 y1 x2 y2)
  (sqrt (+ (sqr (- x2 x1)) 
           (sqr (- y2 y1)))))
```

Note that this is exactly the same as the one above. Beginner books don't usually use this since it's confusing since defining a function is putting a name to a function object and the binding is in the same environment as any other value binding.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other correct answers, I'd like to try to help you to read the original error message. What it's saying is that it expects a lambda to be of the form

```
(lambda (variable more-variable ...) expression)
```

Compare this to your lambda:

```
(lambda X1 Y1 X2 Y2 (sqrt (+ (sqr (- X2 X1)) (sqr (- Y2 Y1))))))
```

do any differences jump out at you? Hopefully, you'll notice that the expected form has parentheses right after the `lambda` keyword, and that your program is missing them.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I might recommend using some data abstraction to maintain practicality of your procedure

```
(define (point x y)
  (cons x y))

(define (point-x p)
  (car p))

(define (point-y p)
  (cdr p))

(define (point-difference p1 p2)
  (point (- (point-x p1) (point-x p2))
         (- (point-y p1) (point-y p2))))

(define (cartesian-distance p1 p2)
  (let ((diff (point-difference p1 p2)))
    (sqrt (+ (sqr (point-x diff))
             (sqr (point-y diff))))))

(cartesian-distance (point 0 0) (point 3 4)) ;; => 5
```

---

Or, if allowed, you can use [`struct`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html)s to accomplish the same thing

```
(struct point (x y) #:transparent)

(define (point-difference p1 p2)
  (point (- (point-x p1) (point-x p2))
         (- (point-y p1) (point-y p2))))

(define (cartesian-distance p1 p2)
  (let ((diff (point-difference p1 p2)))
    (sqrt (+ (sqr (point-x diff))
             (sqr (point-y diff))))))

(cartesian-distance (point 0 0) (point 3 4)) ;; => 5
```